# Nested Cursors over two different Stores

Tags: xodus

I have following code:

```
...

Transaction xodusTransaction = xodusEnvironment.beginReadonlyTransaction();

Store leftStore = xodusEnvironment.openStore(leftName, StoreConfig.USE_EXISTING, xodusTransaction, false);

Store rightStore = xodusEnvironment.openStore(rightName, StoreConfig.USE_EXISTING, xodusTransaction, false);

try(Cursor leftCursor = leftStore.openCursor(xodusTransaction);
Cursor rightCursor = rightStore.openCursor(xodusTransaction)) {

  while(leftCursor.getNext()) {
    while(rightCursor.getNext()) {
    // Do actual work with data from both stores
    }
  }
}
...
```

I expect that internal loop will be fired N*M times, where N - cardinality of leftStore and M - cardinality of rightStore.

On practice external loop fires only once and internal loop fires M-times.

If I rewrite the code in following way (flattering nested loops):

```
...
while(leftCursor.getNext()) {
 ...
}

while(rightCursor.getNext()) {
 ...
}

...
```

Then both loops fires as expected N-times for leftStore and M-times for rightStore.

The question is: is it possible to make nested cursor traveling? If yes, kindly please guide me.

Thank you!

-Taras

Comment: It seems that only one Cursor can travel over / read particular Store at a time. I'm not sure that it is something what we can say "expected behavior".

Comment: Anyway, any help or clarification is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once `cursor.getNext()` returned `false` (there is no *next* key/value pair), it will never return `true` for this Cursor instance. To traverse a Store again, reopen cursor.

Here is the code traversing two Stores as a matrix, i.e. all pairwise combinations of key/value pairs from both Stores:

```
try (Cursor leftCursor = leftStore.openCursor(txn)) {
    while (leftCursor.getNext()) {
        try (Cursor rightCursor = rightStore.openCursor(txn)) {
            while (rightCursor.getNext()) {
                // Do actual work with data from both stores
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Vyacheslav, thank you! Your code makes sense is super easy and quite obvious solution that I did not think about. Thank you. Will mark this answer as accepted.